# When will the "raise_exception=True" pass through the is_valid() function?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

**My Serializer.py**

in this MovieSerializer I will check if "name" and "description" is same or not, if same then raise an error.

```
class MovieSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    name = serializers.CharField(max_length=80)
    description = serializers.CharField(max_length=300)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Movie.objects.create(**validated_data)
    
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.name = validated_data.get('name', instance.name)
        instance.description = validated_data.get('description', instance.description)
        instance.save()
        return instance
    
    
    # object level validation
    def validate(self, data):
        if data['name'] == data['description']:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Name and Description can not be Same.")
        else:
            return data
```

**My views.py**

in **serializer.is_valid()** not pass **raise_exception=True**, when 'name' and 'description' is same it return a formated error message. output :

[image: My error message]

```
class MovieListAV(APIView):

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = MovieSerializer(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
       
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**My another serializer**

validate "password" and "confirm_password" same or not, if different then raise an error.

```
class UserPasswordChangeSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, style={'input_type':'password'})
    confirm_password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, style={'input_type':'password'})

    class Meta:
        fields = ['password', 'confirm_password']
    
    def validate(self, attrs):
        password = attrs.get('password')
        password2 = attrs.get('confirm_password')

        if password != password2:
            raise serializers.ValidationError({'password':'Password and Confirm Password Should be Same!'})
        user = self.context.get('user')
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return attrs
```

**My other view**

serializer.is_valid() not pass raise_exception=True, when "password" and "confirm_password" is dirrerent it can't return any formated error message.
[image: inside postman no response]

but when I use "raise_exception=True" as a parameter of is_valid() like serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True) then I got formated error message.

my question is, why this time I need to pass "raise_exception=True" ? but "MovieListAV" class view no need to pass "raise_exception=True" in is_view()

```
class UserPasswordChange(APIView):
    authentication_classes = [JWTAuthentication, ]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, ]

    def post(self, request, *agrs, **kwargs):
        user = User.objects.get(email=request.user)
        serializer = UserPasswordChangeSerializer(data=request.data, context={'user':user})

        if serializer.is_valid():
            return Response({'success':'Password Change successfull.'}, status=status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED)
    
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_304_NOT_MODIFIED)
```

Comment: Please add the response of both variants you are getting for the change password view.

Comment: I can't understand. Please Can you write the code here??

Comment: We need the response you are currently getting for the different approaches you tried. Without the response and any error message we can’t help you.